# Cannot run perl script with sudo

Tags: linux, redhat, perl

I have a perl script (`test.pl`). If I run this cript by command `perl test.pl`, it work as normal. However, when I run command `sudo perl test.pl`, the error below occurs:

> Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .)

I think it is strange, because I run script by `root`. Do you know why?

Comment: Is there any difference between `perl -V` and `sudo perl -V`? We are interested in the value of `@INC` array.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The returns of two commands are very different, and the @INC also different too.

Comment: I posted it as an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get such an error if the module you are using is not installed which seems not our case here.

The other possibility is to have a different `@INC` array between the two users you are running as. You can verify this using:

```
$ perl -V
$ sudo perl -V
```

Compare the output to see the different paths in `@INC`. You can then fix the `@INC` by adding the missing path or install the needed module in one of the already defined paths.

Comment: How do you add missing path to @INC with `sudo perl -V`?  When I update PERL5LIB in ~/.bashrc this only updates the @INC in the `perl -V`.

Comment: I am having the same problem!